# How to load plugins from my vimrc and from another file?

Tags: vimrc, plugin-system, plugin-vim-plug

I have my dotfiles synchronized on github which is a current practice.

As I use several machines I want to be able to have some part of my configuration not synched on my github repo. To do so I added these lines in my synched `.vimrc`:

```
let $MYLOCALVIMRC = $HOME . "/.local.vim"
if filereadable($MYLOCALVIMRC)
    source $MYLOCALVIMRC
endif
```

Which allows me to add some configuration to `~/.local.vim` which isn't synched.

This works well but now I'd like to extend that to the plugins: I'd like to have some plugins only loaded on some machines.

I'm using [vim-plug](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug) as my plugin manager and it is not possible to call `plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')` and `plug#end()` several times. Even when changing the directory of `plug#begin()`.

The only solution I could imagine was to use a second plugin manager for the local vimrc but it is pretty ugly and I think that it might create some conflicts on the runtime path.

**TL;DR** Is it possible, using a plugin manager, to load some plugins in a `.vimrc` file and some other plugins in a local configuration file sourced by the first `.vimrc`?

Comment: Why not just build up a list of plugins to load, and then load them in a for loop at the end of `.vimrc`? Surely your plugin manager supports loading a function via a function call?

Comment: @jpaugh because that would mean modifying my vimrc on each of the different machines, which would imply  some additional operations when pushing/pulling my dotfiles from my git repo. I agree that they are minor operations but with this method it is totally transparent.

Comment: Wait, I think I'm missing something. I thought you wanted to have a separate `.local.vim` for each machine? You could add to the plugins list in the local file, then load them all in the main `.vimrc`. Creating the plugin list, and loading all plugins would happen in the `.vimrc`, but running the local script in between would give it the chance to modify the list of plugins.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean: in your first comment you suggested adding lines to my `vimrc` which is not what I want. Now you suggest adding lines to a `local.vimrc` which is indeed what I want and what the solution of VanLaser says. I also don't understand what you mean with the for loop (I know what a for loop is but I don't understand what you want to do with it)

Comment: Yes. If you set up an (empty) list of plugins to load in your `.vimrc` file, the call the machine-local script, then that script can add whatever it want to that list. Each local script could add something different, and the `.vimrc` would treat it the same way in each case. Finally, the main `.vimrc` would load the plugins mentioned in the list. Does that make sense?

Comment: I haven't tried it, but it seems like the most robust, and simplest solution. It is more general than VanLaser's solution, because it allows the main `.vimrc` more flexibility in how it choses to load the plugins, making it usable with other plugin managers, e.g. `vim-addon-manager`, which is what I had in mind. However, if VanLaser's solution works for your plugin manager, then go with it. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(I **haven't** tested this)

You could use another local file, that contains exclusively `Plug ...` commands. The main *vimrc* would load this, *inside* the `plug#begin` - `plug#end` section. Something like:

```
let $MYLOCALPLUGINS = $HOME . "/.local.plugins.vim"

plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')
Plug '...'

" load local plugins
if filereadable($MYLOCALPLUGINS)
    source $MYLOCALPLUGINS
endif

Plug '...'
plug#end()

let $MYLOCALVIMRC = $HOME . "/.local.vim"
if filereadable($MYLOCALVIMRC)
    source $MYLOCALVIMRC
endif
```

---

Alternatively (and simpler), just move the `$MYLOCALVIMRC` creation above `plug#begin`, and load the extra (locally-used) plugins directly in the main vimrc, on condition that this local vimrc exists:

```
let $MYLOCALVIMRC = $HOME . "/.local.vim"

plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')
Plug '...'

" load local plugins HERE
if filereadable($MYLOCALVIMRC)
    Plug '...'
    Plug '...'
endif

Plug '...'
plug#end()

if filereadable($MYLOCALVIMRC)
    source $MYLOCALVIMRC
endif
```

Comment: Sourcing another file between `plug#begin()` and `plug#end()` is pretty simple but on first tests it seems like its working, thanks! Also I'm not sure I understand what you exactly mean on your alternative solution.

Comment: You're welcome :) Re: alternative, I added an example to the answer.

Comment: Oh I get your example now but the interesting point with the local file is that my "local" plugins are not synched on github, if I write them directly in the versionned `.vimrc` I'll find them on my other machines (even if they are not sourced).

Comment: If the plugins are "truly" local (e.g. you are making your own plugins, experimental etc.), you don't need `Plug` (while you can use it) - simply add your path to the `runtimepath` in your local vimrc.

Comment: You're right for this point. But I didn't expressed myself clearly: I meant if I create a `if` in my `vimrc` which checks if a file exists to install some plugins , the content of this `if` (i.e. The plugins I want only on this machine, i.e. The lines `Plug '. ..' `) will still appear in my `vimrc` which isn't convenient. Anyway I've been testing your first solution for some days and it is exactly what I was looking for so I'm accepting your answer. Thanks again :-)

Comment: Just want to add that I wanted to do something similar and came across [Chris Toomey's dotfiles](https://github.com/christoomey/dotfiles) where he does _exactly_ what this answer is proposing. And I've since implemented it, too. It does work.