# Same vimrc, customized per machine

Tags: vimrc

I use the same versioned .vimrc on several machines.

Is there a way of customise that file to enable/disable a plugin based on machine name or something like that?

As example, I have something like that in my .bash_profile:

```bash
# common things
...

if [[ $(uname) == "Darwin" ]]
then
     # mac settings
else
     # linux settings
fi
```

Comment: I think this is a duplicate: http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/4721/1841 or at least pretty related. The idea is to put a customized vimrc on each machine containing its own plugins.

Comment: Yes, and I think keeping a separate machine-specific file is the most robust/hassle free way to go. The `.vimrc` doesn't have to "know" anything about which machine it is on; and, you would never touch your `.vimrc` file directly ever again, except to update all of them together, avoiding the chance to accidentally get them out of sync.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can access your environment variable and external command from vim, so you can do:

```
if system('uname') =~ "Darwin"
     echo 'mac'
else
     echo 'other'
endif
```

Note that you can use `=~` instead of `==` to match the regex instead of the exact string (on my machine, `uname` gives me a newline).

or

```
if exists('$TMUX')
  echo 'in tmux'
else
  echo 'not in tmux'
endif
```

Answer (score 10):

In order not to depend on external commands my suggestion would be to use something like the following:

```
if has('mac')
     echo 'mac'
elseif has('win32') || has('win64')
     echo 'windows'
elseif has('unix')
     echo 'unix/linux'
else
     echo 'something else'
endif
```

Comment: This works in MacVim, but not in the version included in macOS, where `has('mac')` (and `has('macunix')`) both return `0`. (Tested most recently in High Sierra).

Answer (score 7):

Provided that you (or your system) can export the environmental variables that you need, you can do something like this in your `.vimrc` (here I use the `vim-plug` plugin manager as an example, and HOSTNAME is the exported variable you want to check):

```
filetype off
call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')
...
if executable('ctags') && $HOSTNAME == 'macintosh'
    Plug 'Shougo/unite-outline'
    Plug 'tsukkee/unite-tag'
    Plug 'ludovicchabant/vim-gutentags'
endif
...
call plug#end()
```

It's also common to use `has()` (e.g. `has ("gui_running")` or `has ("python")`) to decide to install certain plugins.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a direct answer to the question, but I think is still a reasonable solution.

The way I handle this is I have several .vimrc files:

- `vimrc-all` - All common things
- `vimrc-win` - Windows configuration
- `vimrc-linux` - Linux configuration
- `vimrc-workMachine` - Things specific to my work machine
- `vimrc-homeMachine` - Things specific to my home machine

On my workMachine, I create a symlink from `~/.vimrc` to `~/dotfiles/vimConfig/vimrc-workMachine`.

This is what my `vimrc-workMachine` looks like:

```
" ======================================
" Source general vim config
" ======================================
source ~/dotfiles/vimConfig/vimrc-all.vim
source ~/dotfiles/vimConfig/vimrc-linux.vim

" ======================================
" All other stuff
" ======================================
```