# Sourcing Vimplug plugins in a separate file

Tags: vimrc, plugin-system, plugin-vim-plug

Installing plugins through vim-plug involves putting the following code inside the vimrc file.

```
call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')

Plug 'user/repository'

call plug#end()
```

I install a lot of plugins, and I don't want to put all the code inside the main configuration file. I'd instead like to source it from a separate file dedicated to plugins.

I name that file as `Plugins.vim` and source it inside the main `vimrc` file putting the following in the first line.

```
source $HOME/.vim/Plugins.vim
```

Unfortunately, the plugins don't get loaded, and even though Vim reads the file, it outputs error messages relating to that line where it is being asked to source.

I tried to fix it by changing the path and file permissions but with no results.

Note:
The vimrc file may be located inside the home directory as `.vimrc` or in `.vim` directory as `vimrc`.

The error is:

> E471: Argument required

It is either related to `source` or the file itself (I set file's permission to `777`, but I remember sometimes it did not open the file and issued file is unreadable error as well.)

Currently, I am using one file the `.vimrc` as sourcing doesn't work for me.

Comment: What are the error messages?

Comment: Maybe not a duplicate but strongly related: [How to load plugins from my vimrc and from another file?](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/4721/1841). I think adding the test with `filereadable()` could help you.

Comment: I've updated my post and added the error.

Comment: Why the file should be unreadable? Or is it the quotes for source '' "", should I pass a variable and not a quoted path string to source?

Comment: @Chinggiss6 Where do you have quotes? Note, `"` in your vimrc usually denotes the start of a comment, so this would explain why your `:source` command does not see an argument!

Comment: Could you post your vimrc and plugins.vim somewhere (gist?)

Answer (score 1):

I would go with either

```
" load Plugins.vim, searching it in "all vim places"
runtime Plugins.vim
```

or

```
" load Plugins.vim from the relative path of your vimrc
source <sfile>:h/.vim/Plugins.vim
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, you have to call `call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')`, only then you can source the plugin file. It is good practice to have the plugins in a separate file btw!

Comment: No, it should work with a simple `:source`

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt: I agree with you, but he clearly states, that he sources the plugin file in the **first** line of `vimrc`, only later does he call `plug`. That is the problem, the examples for plug clearly state: first call plugged, then source any plugins.

Comment: he said he put the complete plug section into a new file. That should work. However, as I have commented, I believe the problem is actually that he quoted the file (as he stated in a comment later, but not in the example he showed)

Answer (score 0):

Inside my vimrc I have a line that loads my plugins like this

```
source ~/.vim/rc/bundles.vim
```

Then inside my bundles.vim I do the following:

```
call plug#begin('~/.vim/bundle')
  Plug 'foo/vim-someplugin'
  source ~/.vim/rc/plugins/someplugin.vim
call plug#end()
```

if you don't want to use hard coded paths I recommend something like this

```
execute 'source' fnamemodify(expand('<sfile>'), ':h') . '/path/to/file.vim'
```

or

```
source <sfile>:h/.vim/Plugins.vim
```

as Maxim pointed out