# How can I share a vimrc file with all system users file still allowing customisation?

Tags: vimrc

I am creating a `.vimrc` that will be shared by all the users on the system, ie it will be set from `/etc/skel`. However after starting it should be able to load the users own customizations, which normally go into `.vimrc` itself.
The `~/.vimrc` file its actually symlinked to the central file, which should then load the users own customisations, which could be a file named `~/.vimcustomrc`.

What command, if there is one, should be used for that?

It is something like the Apache webserver looking in /etc/apache/conf.d and adding the vhosts the to the default `apache2.conf` or additional repositories being loaded from the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` directory

Comment: Linking this for reference - http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/4721/how-to-load-plugins-from-my-vimrc-and-from-another-file?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add `source` command at the end of the main `.vimrc`, like so:

```
if filereadable(expand("$HOME/.vimcustomrc"))
   execute "source " . expand("$HOME/.vimcustomrc")
endif
```

Answer (score 4):

The right way to do this is to follow the explanation in `:help startup` and to put customizations that are to be shared by all users into `$VIM/vimrc` or `/etc/vimrc`, depending on how Vim was built. Execute `:version` and look for `system vimrc file`. See also `:help system-vimrc`.

The files in `/etc/skel` are generally used to initialize a user's private customizations and not to be the system-wide customizations.

Then each user can customize Vim they way they want to by editing their `~/.vimrc` file, which you've initialized in `/etc/skel`, the way it's documented and the way everyone else does instead of having to discover and use some other file, in this case `~/.vimcustomrc`, which no one else in the world uses. This will make maintaining Vim easier for you and for your users.

Comment: The system I am devising is for myself. I use separate accounts for different tasks on Linux, such as managing a website in one account name and doing programming and compilation in another. I want a common configuration for the commonly used tasks and customized configurations for each account and the work done with it.

Comment: If I want to share some plugins across all accounts, where should they be stored, and how should they be configured in `.vimrc` or `$VIM/vimrc`?

Comment: They go in `$VIM/vimfiles`, that is, in the subdirectories `$VIM/vimfiles/plugin`, `$VIM/vimfiles/syntax`, etc. See also `:help vimfiles`. There is no need to specify their location in any vimrc: that location is already in the default value of 'runtimepath'. If you need to set any plugin-specific global variables for their configuration, then I suppose those settings could go into the system vimrc, which is usually either `/etc/vimrc` or `$VIM/vimrc`. You can find out how your Vim is configured by executing `:version` and looking for the `system vimrc file:`.