# VimPlug#begin in both vimrc and init.vim?

Tags: vimrc, neovim, plugin-vim-plug

I'm new to neovim settings. I'm migrating from vim  to neovim. My question is described in the comment below, `(*)`.

---

In `../init.vim` I have:

```
set runtimepath^=~/.vim runtimepath+=~/.vim/after
let &packpath = &runtimepath
source ~/.vim/vimrc

call plug#begin('~/.vim/vim-plug-in')   " <-------- can I call it again here? (*)
...
call plug#end()
```

In `../vimrc` I have:

```
...
call plug#begin('~/.vim/vim-plug-in') 
" Vim UI 
Plug 'mhinz/vim-startify'
Plug 'vim-airline/vim-airline'
Plug 'cseelus/vim-colors-tone'
Plug 'morhetz/gruvbox'
Plug 'rrethy/vim-hexokinase', { 'do': 'make hexokinase' }
...
call plug#end()
```

Btw, from a 5 years ago [answer on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/neovim/comments/3z6c2i/how_does_one_install_vimplug_for_neovim/cyjlcub?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3): It seems like the what passed to `plug#begin()` can be different, and then it will work?

Comment: [A somehow related question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/4721/1841) I asked a few years ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only call `plug#begin()` and `plug#end()` once, so no this will not work.

You can define all your plug-ins from the same place (such as the `vimrc` file) and use a conditional to detect whether you're running NeoVim to load plug-ins you only want on NeoVim:

```
call plug#begin('~/.vim/vim-plug-in') 
" Vim + NeoVim plug-ins
if has('nvim')
  " NeoVim-only plug-ins
endif
call plug#end()
```