# Github Copilot indentation

Tags: vimrc

Has anyone had any luck getting a good .vimrc configuration to work with GitHub's Copilot insertions? I seem to have two mutually exclusive cases.

1. My normal .vimrc indents everything as expected when working in c, but will overly indent any insertions by Copilot. (it appears Copilot trys to insert the correct indentation, then my .vimrc rules indent those again)
2. I turn off my normal indentation rules in my .vimrc and all insertions by Copilot look great, but now I don't have proper indentation when writing my own code.

Here are the relevant bits of my .vimrc for case 1 and 2 above.

#### Case 1

```
set nu
set nowrap
execute pathogen#infect()
syntax on
filetype plugin indent on
set shiftwidth=4
autocmd FileType c,cpp,h set cindent cinoptions=:0,l1,t0,g0,(0,W4s
set backspace=indent,eol,start  " more powerful backspacing
```

#### Case 2

```
set nu
set nowrap
execute pathogen#infect()
syntax on
filetype plugin indent on
set backspace=indent,eol,start  " more powerful backspacing
```

Comment: Welcome to Vi and Vim SE. Is this question about Github Copilot or Autopilot? You use both names, seemingly interchangeably. If you don't know what you're asking about, how should anybody be able to answer? FWIW, I did a brief evaluation of Copilot a while ago and I didn't notice any issues, indentation or otherwise.

Comment: So how do you start the Github Copilot? Perhaps when starting it, you can automaticall `:setl nocindent` and when stopping it automatically `:setl cindent`? But it is not clear, how you run it

Comment: @Friedrich thanks for pointing that out. Just Copilot, not sure why I wrote Autopilot so many times without noticing. Made the edits.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt it automatically starts from the `execute pathogen#infect()` line in the`.vimrc` by having the copilot repo located in `~/.vim/bundle/`. I guess I can look at a way to change the pathogen config perhaps to load things like you suggest. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: These things happen and I could have been a bit more polite pointing it out. But Christian is right, we don't see the interesting parts. I would suspect it's only superficially related to Copilot.

Comment: so how do you start Vim then when you *do not* want to have Copilot enabled??

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt I haven't found a time that I needed to have it disabled so far. I'm not looking to have a working config without it. Maybe my wording was confusing in the question. I currently have two mutually exclusive configs, but I'm aiming to have one unified config. Does that make more sense?

Comment: There are different ways to make this possible: Use different Vimrcs (e.g. with a shell alias), use a single vimrc and only source parts of your plugins, if a certain environment variable is set, etc.. But perhaps this question covers it already for you? https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/4721/how-to-load-plugins-from-my-vimrc-and-from-another-file